# schtasks - create task with no schedule that runs on demand

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

I am trying to use `schtasks.exe` and create a one-time task that runs on demand. I just want to create the task without a schedule but the command `schtasks /create /tn TestTask` fails with `Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'sc' is missing.`. Is there an option i am missing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the task and set it to start ONCE in the past.  The task will exist and you can run it at will.

Comment: This does not work on my machine - any other workaround you know of? We scheduled the task with ONCE on 1/1/2999, however, that's not a clean solution.

Comment: @D.R. We have a time traveler! For the rest of us, 1/1/2999 is not in the past. It's also after January 19, 2038 03:14:08 GMT, [The End of Unix Time](http://unixepoch.com/). That's why it didn't work on your machine.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a dummy time in the past or future, you can set the task to run on a dummy event:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN TaskOnEvent /TR notepad.exe /SC ONEVENT /EC Application /MO *[System/EventID=777] /f
```

Then you can run it on demand:

```
SCHTASKS /Run /TN "TaskOnEvent"
```

Or trigger it by logging the event:

```
EVENTCREATE /ID 777 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION /SO DummyEvent /D "Initiate scheduled task."
```

..Or create task in gui, export and call xml:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "TaskOnEvent" /xml "C:\TaskOnEvent.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

`/sc ONCE /st 00:00` should be sufficient to create a task that never triggers by its own and needs to be triggered explicitly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already you can create task in gui, export and call xml:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "TaskOnEvent" /xml "C:\TaskOnEvent.xml"
```

...You do **NOT** have to specify any triggers if you create via the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

`/sc once /st 00:00` will not work because you can't schedule a task in the past. But if you use the the CURRENT TIME, it will work, and the task will never be executed ... (but you'll get a warning though) .... tested under Windows 10 ...

`/sc once /st 20:56`for this post !